# Since when are users required to be logged in to ask questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, logout

A few months ago I asked an anonymous question using an unregistered account on Super User. However I now see a message that you must be logged in to ask a question on Super User.

When and why did this change happen?

Usually when a change like this is made there is an announcement on Meta but I could not find such an announcement.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That thread seems specific to [so].

Comment: @user16217248 Please post a link to the SU question you asked anonymously.  It might be that it was not anonymous as you think if this was a few months ago. I was never aware anyone could ever submit anonymous questions so that's news to me. I think you will need to show an example even though it's regarding something you wish to be kept "anonymous" or else they will close your question. I encourage you to pick such an example answer to be investigated further; otherwise, it was likely not anonymous. I'll keep an eye on this post to see what comes of it.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I've seen a few question by ***unregistered*** accounts but not recently. I think this is what the OP means.

Comment: [You must be logged in to ask a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/login?returnurl=https://meta.superuser.com/questions/ask&ssrc=anon_ask) might be the reason

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Please note that the question currently on my profile about Firefox is *not* the question I asked anonymously.

Comment: If I were to guess it probably got changed by someone on the staff during the moderator strike as an attempt to try and stem some of the spam flood. I doubt it did anything to stop the spam but I can't say I'm against keeping things the way they are, a small minority of unregistered users are an absolute menace.

Comment: @1NN It has been possible to add a name, and an email to a 'post as guest' box, and then you will have a cookie-based 'unregistered' account. But your email could be any random/nonexistent email. On some sites, you must fully verify your account. On others you can ask/answer with unregistered accounts. On Stack Overflow, you can answer, but not ask questions, with unregistered accounts.

Comment: @1NN And I absolutely remember asking a question, on May 10, using an **unregistered** account.